# How can I load google recaptcha asyncly?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, recaptcha

After implementing googles no captcha, my website page loading is noticeably slow.

The problem comes from this, which is used in `<head></head>`

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

How can I load this aysncly with javascript maybe, and have the captcha display after the page loads?

I tried:

```
function loadCaptcha(){

    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'row';

    div.innerHTML = "";
    div.innerHTML += "<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>";
    div.innerHTML += "<form action='' method='post''><div align=\"center\" id='centercaptcha' class=\"g-recaptcha\" data-sitekey=\"***\"></div><br><button name='Claim faucet' value='Claim faucet' id='faucet-button'>Claim faucet</button></form>";

    document.getElementById('center').appendChild(div);

    //document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}
```

yet no cigar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Move your script tag to the bottom.
2. [Use async](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp).

Comment: by bottom do you mean <footer> tag? Please clarify

Comment: By bottom, I mean the most bottom part of your HTML code where a `<script>` tag doesn't break the HTML specs. A footer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Google's instruction to use `async defer` in `<script>`-block:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```